# Change log level for smallrye kafka consumer extension

Tags: logging, kafka-consumer-api, quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging, quarkus-kafka

I have a quarkus app which uses the `quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-kafka` extension.

At runtime it produces a tons of debug logs:

```
rent-orchestrator-service    | 16:44:11.508 [smallrye-kafka-consumer-thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=kafka-consumer-rent-service-events, groupId=rent-orchestrator-service] Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition rent-service-events-0 at position FetchPosition{offset=0, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[kafka:9092 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=0}} to node kafka:9092 (id: 1 rack: null)
rent-orchestrator-service    | 16:44:11.508 [smallrye-kafka-consumer-thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer clientId=kafka-consumer-rent-service-events, groupId=rent-orchestrator-service] Built incremental fetch (sessionId=1774069795, epoch=565) for node 1. Added 0 partition(s), altered 0 partition(s), removed 0 partition(s), replaced 0 partition(s) out of 1 partition(s)
rent-orchestrator-service    | 16:44:11.508 [smallrye-kafka-consumer-thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer clientId=kafka-consumer-rent-service-events, groupId=rent-orchestrator-service] Sending READ_UNCOMMITTED IncrementalFetchRequest(toSend=(), toForget=(), toReplace=(), implied=(rent-service-events-0), canUseTopicIds=True) to broker kafka:9092 (id: 1 rack: null)
rent-orchestrator-service    | 16:44:11.508 [smallrye-kafka-consumer-thread-0] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=kafka-consumer-rent-service-events, groupId=rent-orchestrator-service] Sending FETCH request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FETCH, apiVersion=12, clientId=kafka-consumer-rent-service-events, correlationId=678) and timeout 30000 to node 1: FetchRequestData(clusterId=null, replicaId=-1, maxWaitMs=500, minBytes=1, maxBytes=52428800, isolationLevel=0, sessionId=1774069795, sessionEpoch=565, topics=[], forgottenTopicsData=[], rackId='')
```

I tried to set a different log level in the `application.properties` but it doesn't work:

```
quarkus.log.level=INFO
quarkus.log.category."org.apache.kafka".level=INFO
```

How can I solve?

Comment: What about these other options https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka#logging ?

Comment: They don't work. Debug logs are always printed

Comment: Is there any other log option are you setting in your properties?

Comment: What is the Quarkus version are you using?

Comment: I solved. I had a transitive dependency from another logger, which was in conflict with the default logger of quarkus. Now debug logs are not printed :)
In gradle I have excluded that transitive dependency using `exclude group: 'group-name', module: 'artifact-name'`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do not have another logger in your classpath. So, if you are using maven, check with `mvn dependency:tree` and exclude any logger that may be pulled:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>foo-that-pull-another-logger</groupId>
   <artifactId>...</artifactId>
   <version>...</version>
   <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
        <groupId>the-other-logger-groupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>the-other-logger-artifactid</artifactid>
     </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Then, in the `application.properties`, add (as you did)

```
quarkus.log.level=INFO
quarkus.log.category."org.apache.kafka".level=INFO
```